# Windows 10 won't install with dual boot on NVMe SSD

Tags: windows, ubuntu, drivers, ssd, windows-installation

I recently bouth a new PC with a Samsung 980 SSD NVMe. I installed there Ubuntu 20.04 without any problem, but when I try to install Windows 10, it won't let me.

When I boot from the USB and the Windows 10 installer starts, it shows a message saying that I need some drive drivers to continue. I tried to look into Samsung page but apparently there's no driver for my SSD as Windows 10 should be able to recognize it.

I have tried different things as this: https://linustechtips.com/topic/1191861-windows-wont-install-on-nvme-ssd-that-has-linux-installed-on-it/

And I also have read that it may be needed to format the SSD and leave it clean, but as I already have information on my Ubuntu partition, I would rather not to do it, only as a last resource.

Is there any other solution or I just have to clean the SSD before installing Windows? Thank you very much.

PS: I created the bootable USB from Ubuntu following this tutorial: https://techbit.ca/2019/02/creating-a-bootable-windows-10-uefi-usb-drive-using-linux/

Comment: Not sure of a solution to your problem, but for people checking this page in the future: I normally install Windows first if I'm dual booting on the same drive. I run into far fewer issues that way

Comment: This might help perhaps: Check your BIOS configuration and verify that "PCH Storage Configuration" is set to "Raid Mode", or that "NAND/Storage Remapping option” is enabled. The actual names may be different. Have you changed anything in the BIOS in order to install Linux?

Comment: I never had any issue installing Windows after Ubuntu in dual-boot but always using UEFI mode (with BIOS it was a different story but the only hurdle was reinstalling Grub when use a single drive). But it's not clear you want a dual-boot or just install Windows instead of Ubuntu (your link seems about the latter). Even more important is knowing in what mode was Ubuntu installed and the partitioning type (GPT or old MBR) as that will determine what you can do now if not reinstalling Ubuntu. The error message you speak of is likely NOT related with drivers but about an incompatible partitioning.

Comment: Windows strictly requires GPT for UEFI mode (preferred) or MBR for Legacy/"BIOS"/CSM. How you boot the installation media is how it installs. Any Windows or Ubuntu media (except when made with Rufus) can boot either way, how you select one or other option at boot (in UEFI with Legacy enabled) is what determines the installation mode. Please [edit] the question accordingly and post the missing information I commented above and what exactly you want to do. A dual-boot is different then replacing one with the other.